# Find an appropriate queue-consumer pair

Tags: java, message-queue, spring-integration

I need to implement with the help of spring-intagration libraries a message pipeline. At the beginning, as I see now, it needs to contain several elements:

a. Messaging gateway,

```
@MessagingGateway(name = "entryGateway", defaultRequestChannel = "requestChannel")
public interface MessageGateway {
    public boolean  processMessage(Message<?> message);
}
```

which is called when I want to start the pipeline:

```
messageGateway.processMessage(message);
```

b. Channel for transmitting the messages:

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel requestChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
}
```

c.Router which decides then where flow the messages

```
@MessageEndpoint
@Component
public class MessageTypeRouter {
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MessageTypeRouter.class);

    @Router(inputChannel="requestChannel")
    public String processMessageByPayload(Message<?> message){...}
```

There can be many incoming messages in a small period of time, so I wanted to realize a channel (b) as QueueChannel:

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel requestChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel();
}
```

On the other hand I would like the router to start as soon as a message comes through gateway and the other messages to wait in the queue. But in this case I received an error, which said that I should have used a poller.

May be you could give me a piece of advice, how I can realize my scheme. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As we know with XML config we must declare a `<poller>` component and mark it with `default="true"`. That allows any `PollingConsumer` endpoint to pick up the `default` Poller from the context.

With Java config we must declare a `@Bean` for similar purpose:

```
@Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
public PollerMetadata defaultPoller() {
    PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
    pollerMetadata.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(10));
    return pollerMetadata;
}
```

Where the `PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER` is specific constant to define the `default` poller. Although the same name is used from XML config in case of `default="true"`.

From other side `@Router` annotation has `poller` attribute to specify something similar like we do with nested `<poller>` in XML.

Comment: As you can see, I don't want to use polling semantics. I use message-driven gateway that actually isn't compatible with queueChannel, as I've read. The question is: how can I store multiple incoming messages sing message-driven semantics.

Comment: OK. How about `ExecutorChannel`? Any incoming message will wait for the free `Thread` to be processed in the internal `queue` of `ThreadPollTaskExecutor`

Comment: This is my pipleline: gateway -> channel -> Router -> further things.
I need to implement Router and others as Runnable if I want to user executorChannel, don't I?

Comment: No. Spring Integration does that for you internally: just wraps `handleMessage` to the `Runnable` for the `TaskExecutor`